# window.load will not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I need to run a function after the HTML on my page has been rendered (because I need to get the height of a particular dynamic div). I have tried several methods, but I cannot get `window.load` to fire (I am using Chrome).

I've placed all of the following code below in the constructor of my TypeScript ViewModel.

This doesn't work:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    ...code...
});
```

And neither does this:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    ...code...
});
```

Or this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { 
    ...code...
});
```

Any ideas why none of these work? If there's another method to go about doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What method are you using to determine that those attempts don't work? Those all do in fact create a handler for the "load" event. (That's assuming that you've imported jQuery and that there aren't any other errors. Have you tried adding some `console.log()` calls?)

Comment: the window load event only happens once during the life of a page. If you're trying to listen to a change after loading in new content, the window load event is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I've placed a breakpoint inside the methods in addition to looking at the result my code should produce. For debugging purposes, I've also put a basic `alert` in the function.

Comment: @KevinB Fair point, but this is when I navigate to a new page.

Comment: Can you clarify? does navigating to a new page create a new `document/window`? or does it just add new dom elements to the existing `document/window`.

Comment: @KevinB To the best of my knowledge it creates a new document/window.

Comment: Then you will need to tie into whatever is creating/populating the "dynamic div", window load clearly isn't going to work in your case as you're applying it after it has occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it inside the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.event.add(window, "load", myFunction);

    myFunction() {
        ...code...
    }
});
```

This worked for me when I had to manipulate a `<div>` based on its height after rendering.

Comment: AFAIK document.ready is pre-rendering or before the DOM is constructed. I've tried this and when my code in my function tries to look for the div that needs to be rendered first, it can't be found. After it's rendered I can go into the console and find it with the same code no problem.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't downvote, but this still doesn't work. Kevin B ended up giving me a suggestion that worked.